# Back to back switching voltage regulator and what to do with capacitance

Tags: capacitor, switching-regulator

I have two ICs firstly [MAX20077ATCA_VY+](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/max20077-max25277.pdf) (a 5V regulator) and secondly [MP2672GD-0000-Z](https://www.monolithicpower.com/en/documentview/productdocument/index/version/2/document_type/Datasheet/lang/en/sku/MP2672/) (a battery charger IC) the first IC is the main voltage supply for the second IC.

For my application the first IC requires 30uF on its 5V output line.  While the second IC requires 10uF on its input line.  These ICs are separated only by about 40mm of trace which is 2mm thick.  I try to put each set of capacitors as close to their IC as possible.

But I am wondering is it necessary what I am doing?  Could I get away with just the 30uF and stick this capacitor midway between the ICs?

Comment: You could also just add the capacitance requirements and go with a single 47µF.

Comment: It's probably also a good idea to add a small ceramic capacitor about 100 nF close to the inputs and outputs

Comment: @PStechPaul what makes you say this?

Comment: The spec sheet for the battery charger IC calls for a 4.7 uF ceramic capacitor on the input as well as a 10 uF capacitor on the output. I would assume the 5V regulator has similar requirements, especially if it is a switching type. The important factor is low ISR and sufficient capacity to hold the voltage steady during switching transients.

Comment: What types of capacitors are you considering? Have you accounted for the tolerance and voltage dependency of some ceramics?

Comment: @Andyaka the MP2672GD suggests using ceramic X7R capacitors (page  38) so this is what I am using.  For MAX20077ATCA, I was planning to use aluminum electrolytic capacitors for the output capacitor and ceramics for the smaller ones.  There are some specifics for this IC and output capacitance on page 13, and it gets pretty detailed not sure I follow.

Comment: You should probably have some ceramic capacitors on the output, not just aluminum.

Comment: I would use two 22uF's, one at each end of the trace. There should probably be some damping in there too, since ceramic ESR is so low. Note the inductance of 40mm trace is about as many nH, which will resonate with the series equivalent (11uF) at Fo = 240kHz and Zo = 60mΩ. Ideally one would have this ESR, or both would have half. An aluminum polymer could be selected with this value.